# Two columns in the same table must match - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

How to add constraint that force the values of two columns in the same table to be identical ?

I want the student class grade match the student grade.

```
/*Student Grade = Student Class Grade constraint "BEFORE INSERT" */ 
delimiter //    
CREATE TRIGGER StCGradeCheckBIN BEFORE INSERT ON  STUDENT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.Class_Grade <> Grade THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error while filling the Class Grade faild! It is must match the Student.Grade feild';
    END IF;
END;
// delimiter ;


/*Student Grade = Student Class Grade constraint "BEFORE UPDATE" */ 

delimiter //    
CREATE TRIGGER StCGCheckBUP BEFORE UPDATE ON  Student
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.Class_Grade <> Grade THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error while Updating the Class Grade feild! It is must mathc  the Student.Grade feild';
    END IF;
END;
// delimiter ;
```

This trigger doesn't work , It causes this error during insert into STUDENT table

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Grade' in 'field list'
```

Using mysql workbench 6.3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the trigger doesn't understand `Grade`.  Because these are on the same table, I think you can just use `new.` to qualify the name:

```
delimiter //    
CREATE TRIGGER StCGradeCheckBIN BEFORE INSERT ON  STUDENT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.Class_Grade <> new.Grade THEN
--------------------------^
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error while filling the Class Grade faild! It is must match the Student.Grade feild';
    END IF;
END;
// delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, but if both columns have to be equal, why do you need the second column? It wouldn't serve any purpose.